# Get thumbnail of word in java using Apache POI with XWPF

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

this question deals with getting the thumbnail of a word doc using HWPF:

[get thumbnail of word in java using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673337/get-thumbnail-of-word-in-java-using-apache-poi)

I want to do this with XWPF - the Apache POI API for word xml documents (.docx). There is no getThumbnail() method, or similar. How can I do this? I want to extract the embedded thumbnail generated by Word using the "generate thumbnail" option in the "Save As..." Dialog - which works fine for .doc documents with HWPF.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade you version of Apache POI! You need to use [Apache POI 3.15 beta 2 or newer](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.15-beta2)

On those newer versions, you'll find a few Thumbnail-related methods on [POIXMLProperties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.html), such as [getThumbnailFilename()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.html#getThumbnailFilename()) and [getThumbnailImage()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.html#getThumbnailImage())

To save the thumbnail image to a file, with XWPF, you'd do something like:

```
XWPFDocument wordDocument = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docxFile));
POIXMLProperties props = workDocument.getProperties();

String thumbnail = props.getThumbnailFilename();
if (thumbnail == null) {
   // No thumbnail
} else {
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\"+thumbnail);
   IOUtils.copy(props.getThumbnailImage(), fos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this improvement of the Apache POI was made because of this request ;-) (see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59717)

Answer (score 0):

After some intense research, especially about Open Packaging Conventions, I found the answer by myself. There is no "getThumbnai()" convenience method in XWPF Document API. The thumbnail must be extract via the specific package relationship:

```
XWPFDocument wordDocument = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docxFile));

ArrayList<PackagePart> packageParts= wordDocument.getPackage().getPartsByRelationshipType
("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/thumbnail");

PackagePart packagePart = packageParts.get(0);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\thumb.emf");
IOUtils.copy(packagePart.getInputStream(), fos);
```

Comment: Thanks for working this out! I've [raised a POI enhancement request for this](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59717). Would be great if you had a chance to contribute this as a full fix!

Comment: This enhancement request was now closed, thumbnail helper methods are now included in http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.15-beta2.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JVM library for making thumbnails, [Thumbnails4j](https://github.com/elastic/thumbnails4j) (I'm a maintainer, but it's owned by [Elastic](https://elastic.co)), that uses POI under the hood for docx files.

```
File input = new File("/path/to/my_file.docx");
Thumbnailer thumbnailer = new DOCXThumbnailer();
List<Dimensions> outputDimensions = Collections.singletonList(new Dimensions(100, 100));
BufferedImage output = thumbnailer.getThumbnails(input, outputDimensions).get(0);
```